# emacs org mode : How to select a page style when exporting to odt?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode, odt

I am exporting an org document to odt using org-odt-export-to-odt (Org-mode version 8.2.6 and emacs 23) and I would like the first page to get the OrgFirstPage style and the following pages to get the OrgPage style.

I tried using a custom style file created by exporting an empty org file to odt and modifying it with LibreOffice so that the first page has the OrgFirstPage style and the second one has the OrgPage style. I referenced it in my org file with #+ODT_STYLES_FILE: but all pages in the exported document have the Standard style.
I'm sure my exported odt file uses my custom style file because I also added a header to the standard page style and I see it in the exported odt file.

Is there a way to set the page style in the org file?

Comment: Yes I think it's pretty obscure, I have no idea how to move table of content later than on 1st page ...